# Who and what is the Resistance left with at the end of The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, the-rebel-alliance

So the Rebels took a pretty big hit. They didn't have a lot at the start of *The Last Jedi*, and they had… almost nothing at the end of *The Last Jedi*. In fact, the entire Resistance (as we know it) appears to be entirely contained within the Millennium Falcon.

So who and what do they have left to fight with in episode IX?

Comment: TFJ? Do you mean TLJ?

Comment: @Blackwood *waves hand* This is not the acronym you're looking for...

Comment: Star Wars: Too many TLAs.

Comment: Mostly what they're left with is hope. When noone answered their call for help, they believed all hope was gone, but we saw it rekindled through Luke's sacrifice and the stories he was already inspiring in potential new rebels. A new hope, if you will.

Comment: `Rebellions are built on hope`.

Comment: In a galaxy filled with trillions of beings, there's nobody else to fight the First Order? What about the New Republic's Starfleet and army?

Comment: Assuming General Organa will pass away in Star Wars IX, there will be few or no experienced and competent leaders in either the First Order or New Republic (at least going by the characters depicted in the film). Maybe the war will just fizzle out as neither side really knows what they're doing? :-)

Comment: Looking for a canon answer is doomed to failure. The Disney canon is puddle deep and nonsensical. The Resistance at the end of TLJ is whatever nonsense Rian Johnson wrote them into. And at the start of the next movie, they'll be whatever Abrams needs them to be to set up his mystery boxes.

Comment: @RobertF The Republic idiotically kept most of their forces around their capital, you presumably saw what happened to both in Force Awakens.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It appears to be the case that only those on the Millennium Falcon survived. So we know of the following active members:

- Leia Organa
- Poe Dameron
- Finn
- Rose Tico
- Rey
- C-3PO
- R2-D2
- BB-8
- Chewbacca
- Lieutenant Connix
- C'ai Threnalli

Other than that I believe Commander D'Acy, Vice Admiral Amilyn Holdo's second in command, is still alive though I'm not 100% on that. I'm also not certain on this but Nien Nunb could have been there at the end.

There are probably some Porgs on the ship after Chewie brought them with him and then there's a handful of other surviving members but I'm not sure if these are named.

Although not active members of the Rebellion Maz Kanata and the Master Codebreaker appear to be on their side and as far as we are aware they are still alive.

As stated above it appears that their only surviving ship at the moment is the Falcon. However, they likely have other abandoned bases like the one on Crait so there's potentially more old abandoned ships left on some planets like the Salt Speeders.

Lastly, as we saw in the films ending scene Luke's final act has inspired the downtrodden to rise up again. The child at the end is either already a rebellion member or is going to be. This is important as it means at the start of the next film the rebellion could be back up to it's usual "strength".

Comment: You forgot BB-8. As we saw in TLJ, he is something of a one-droid army. :-)

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit Don't know how I could forget that little beast. He seems to upstaging R2 even.

Comment: “There are probably some Porgs on the ship” — not for long. Food is scarce.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I wouldn't fight Chewie for one

Comment: Exclusive Episode 9 script excerpt: “RRRRRAAAWWWRRRRGGGG” *[subtitles] PLEASE CONSIDER ONE OF THE MANY VEGAN PORG ALTERNATIVES NOW WIDELY AVAILABLE*

Comment: Nien Numb or is it a different Sullustun, I feel like I saw him at the end. Also one of the other squadron members, Red 6 maybe? Flew a skiff/speeder

Comment: @WraithLeader It is Nien Nunb, couldn't remember if I saw him or not though

Comment: These are the confirmed surviving members of the OFFICIAL Resistance. It's strongly implied in the other material outside of the films (such as the TLJ novelization, and the story mode of Battlefront II) that there are other cells and groups who are Resistance sympathizers, although they aren't yet joined with Leia's group or are operating in different areas of the galaxy.

Comment: @Möoz Force ghosts that can incinerate trees with pinpoint lightning strikes, no less.  Not quite up to the orbital bombardment tier of firepower, but still pretty scary.  Scary, scary ghosts.

Answer (score 11):

#### Question: Who and what is the Rebellion left with at the end of The Last Jedi?

#### Answer to the "what" is *Hope*

That's the point of the last scene with the boy sweeping the floor of straw and gazing out to the stars, while wearing the Ring that looks like Rose's ring.  (Did she give it to him?)  Hope is mentioned in a number of conversations during the movie, particularly as the cruiser is fleeing the First Order fleet and the Admiral is focused on trying to keep some of the resistance alive. (Laura Dern delivered those lines beautifully).

#### The answer to *Who?* (or *whom?*)

Rey, Leia, Poe, Finn, Rose, C-3PO, R2-D2, BB-8, Chewbacca, and the *Millenium Falcon* (which I tend to view as a character/fixture for the rebels since the first movie) and ... the many people alluded to (they are off screen) as *those peoples in the outer rim*.  Granted, they didn't respond to the call for help when Leia's survivors were trapped in the old rebel base, but what could they do?  Again, the little boy in the stable is one of those people who are looking for hope, and who is keeping hope alive.

What hope do they have? The hope that, somehow, the First Order will be opposed and overcome.  These are the people who you can expect to support the Resistance in the next movie.

Rose put this slightly differently when she tells Finn:  "We don't need to kill what we hate, we need to protect those we love"

#### A point on Meta Themes:

The first movie was called *Episode IV: A New Hope*

*Hope* is a long running theme of this series.  In the early scene with Luke and Obi-Wan, [the little hologram of Leia being presented by R2D2 includes the appeal](https://media1.tenor.com/images/2b62869d23e1f9f407691b855cf8fd4a/tenor.gif?itemid=5458893) "...you're my only hope" directed to Obi-Wan.
[image]

The theme of *keeping hope alive* during the course of the entire story arc crops up again and again.  In keeping with the "new hope" and "the young are our hope" theme from the first series (the hopes for Annakin in the first prequel as the one whom the Jedi had been seeking), we see in the ending scene with the stable boy a subtle hint that he may be Force sensitive when the broom moves into his hand.  (Thanks to @HorusKol for pointing that out in a comment).  This fits into hope for the future and underscores Luke's response to Kylo - "I will not be the last Jedi."

Comment: Also, with the stableboy, there's a very subtle hint that he may be Force sensitive as the broom moves into his hand...

Comment: @HorusKol I've only seen the movie once and I seem to have missed that detail.  I'll add that, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They have the leader of the Rebellion, they have a newly discovered Jedi who is only now discovering her power (and who was trained under the only remaining Jedi), and they likely still have other secret bases like the one on the salt planet Crait to rebuild the Rebellion.

Also, they've shown that they can still plant seeds of discontent (dare I say "hope") in the downtrodden (i.e. the stable boy) and possibly enlist their help in rebuilding the Rebellion. The boy also shows signs of being able to harness the force, so he and as yet undiscovered people like him may end up being more powerful than they at first appear. I suspect that he'll be making a comeback in the next episode.

Oh, and I think they have a few [Porgs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Porg) from Ahch-To.

Answer (score 2):

This is just my thoughts on where there might be allies lurking around in the Galaxy, who will actually come to the aid of the splinters of the Resistance.

I'm thinking that the New Republic took a massive blow when several of their worlds blew up in The Force Awakens. But from the Aftermath books and other sources, we might conclude that there are still many worlds that might want to be part of a wave of resistance in order to fight the First Order. They might be afraid, obviously, but they would probably know that the Starkiller Base was also destroyed after that attack. There might still be a lot of troops and ships left as well, who weren't circling or docked on the few worlds that were destroyed by Starkiller Base. I think they might be willing to take the fight to the First Order as the FO is now reeling from the destruction of both the super dreadnought, the Starkiller Base and also the death of Supreme Leader Snoke.

So there might be many who are looking for revenge. And survival.

I'm also thinking that Kashyyyk would still harbor many Wookiees who remember the slaughter and slavery of the Empire and would still be in debt to the remnants of the New Republic. AKA the now resistance/rebels, while also wanting to fight the First Order as they don't want to end up in the same way once again.

I'm also thinking there might still be a few people from the old Ghost crew still alive. We know Sabine Wren is probably still alive, as well as perhaps Ahsoka Tano (who would be an old woman, but still "a grey jedi" by now. Ezra Bridger would be as close to a jedi one could imagine, if still alive, and Hera Syndulla and her (perhaps even force sensitive) son with the now dead Kanan Jarrus would probably be around still. And that would mean there would be connections with the twilek people as well. Also, where is Wedge Antilles? Not dead, is he? So he should be around still? Somewhere? Perhaps returning from a mission somewhere? Or just living elsewhere and might return from pasture, like the old squad he created according to the Aftermath books.

Not sure how many bounty hunters and smugglers, mandalorians (since they might follow Sabine Wren nowadays, after all) might be interested in joining the resistance. And we know nothing about old Lando, except Bespin is still around (in one way or another, according to the Aftermath books). He might still be alive, though, and would probably want to avenge the death of Han Solo. Maz Kanata might not be too happy about her old castle being blown to bits. And she has quite the leverage in some very influential, however "scruffy looking" circles. What might she be up to?

By the way, I am quite certain that even though Luke Skywalker is now a force ghost, he will be a very powerful one. And we have NOT seen the last of him, for sure.

And what about Thrawn? Is he really that happy about the First Order, if he is still alive at this time? And would he and the Chiss feel they are truly safe from Kylo as the new Supreme Leader? Or will they rise up and decide they are safer with the First Order gone?

So I think that even though no one knows anything about what kinds of allies Leia is referencing at the end of The Last Jedi, I think there are many who might turn out to be potential allies and very well much needed reinforcements to the very few people who made it out in the end.

Comment: There needs to be support in canon sources for an answer to be considered a proper one on this site.

Comment: The novels and the animated series are fully accepted as canon according to Disney, and the LucasFilm Story Group.

Comment: Sure, but is any of the answer supported by them? This seems like supposition rather than something in the novels or animated series.

Comment: In part in these works. And also by statements by Lucasfilm officials, i.e. members of the story group.

Comment: Then it’d be a good idea to add the quotes that support this answer. Otherwise it could look like just theories.

Comment: Everything regarding a sequel work that has not been released yet (in this case it hasn't even been filmed yet - they begin shooting the film end of June this year) will ALWAYS be theories. Regardless of whatever story we're talking about. That applies to all of the answers in this thread, as we don't even know if some of the characters listed above are among the ones saved and cramped up in the Falcon. We don't even know if IX will begin exactly where TLJ ends, or if it will be 1, 2, 4 or even 10 years between the two movies. .

Comment: Thing is, the question is "Who might or might not be around and might help these people out in IX?" The question is not "Exactly who are on board the Falcon after Luke and Rey save the day?" And as long as you don't possess JJ Abrams's script for IX, you can probably lock down this entire subject, as there is no answer in the World right now that isn't speculation - or might end up being seen as such come December 2020.

Answer (score 0):

So from what I saw the remaining rebels on crait are:
.General organa

.Captain Poe dameron

Finn

Rose tico

Rey nobody

Chewbacca

Kaydel Co konnix

Larma d'acy

Nien nunb

Cia threnalli

Koo milchum, Saille minau and The other child of mark hamill

Vober dand

C-3po

Bb-8

R2-d2

Porgs

Possibly: General Ematt

Nodin chavdri

Pamich merro goode

Everyone has forgot about the Other resistance members:
Shriv suurgev

Zay versio

Snap wexley

Jess pava

Yolo ziff

Niv lek

Lieutenient bastian

Greer sonnel

Joph seastriker

Also in the last Jedi novel The commander of the fallen bomber squadron is called fossil and he gives rose the resistance ring but I'm not sure if he died

I know they are not official members of the resistance but maz kanata and he codebreaker are Rebel symphatizers and So far we don't know what has happened to the ghost crew and also in the last Jedi novel it states the resistance capital ships were from other Rebel cells that had donated them or went to help them in the evacuation
There you go

Comment: THANK YOU FOR INCLUDING GREER AND JOPH!!! Although fangirl side of me set aside, I'm actually not sure if they should be on this list, as it's unknown whether they are actually still alive at the time of The Last Jedi or not, and they could have been on another Resistance ship that was gunned down by the First Order. And Greer could have already succumbed to her illness before even the time of The Force Awakens.

Answer (score -1):

I saw Finn
Rey
Poe
Nien Numb
C'ai Thernalli
Rose
Leia (not appear in IX)
Salaka Kuchimba
Salie Minnau
Geno Namit
D'Acy
Connix
Koo Millham
Ematt may have survived
Maz and codebraker
Niv Lek
Snap Wexley
Bastain
Jess Pava
Maybe Kix because he was frozen for 50 years which would round up to around episode 9
Porgs
BB-8
R2-D2
C-3PO
maybe Rex and Wolffe and Ketsu
Maybe the ghost crew include Ahsoka
Zay
Shriv Suurgav 
Others who are not confirmed dead
Bollie Prindel
Vober Dand
Cove Nell
Salty Sharp
Derham Boyce 
2-BB-2 
BB-4

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is hard to read at the moment could you [edit] it to read better?

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the right answer is:

- General Organa
- Captain
- Poe Dameron
- Finn
- Rose Tico
- Rey
- Chewbacca
- Kaydel Co konnix
- Larma d'acy
- Nien Nunb
- Cia threnalli
- Koo milchum, Saille minau and The other child of mark hamill
- Vober dand
- C-3PO
- BB-8
- R2-D2
- Porgs

Possibly:

- General Ematt
- Nodin chavdri
- Pamich merro goode

Everyone has forgot about the Other resistance members:

- Shriv suurgev
- Zay versio
- Snap wexley
- Jess pava
- Yolo ziff
- Niv lek
- Lieutenient Bastian
- Greer sonnel
- Joph seastriker

Comment: It would be great if you can point to where these people were that they would have survived.  Otherwise this is just a copy of a previous answer.