# Who is this character and who is the actress?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, the-last-jedi

In *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*, there are several scenes of the Resistance in a base and aboard a cruiser. One character we see frequently is Lt. Connix, played by Billie Lourd. A few times during the movie, a much older woman Resistance officer is seen near Lt. Connix.

She is thin with a fairly sharp nose and a relatively weak chin. I am **not** getting her confused with Laura Dern as Vice Admiral Holdo. I have searched for images to show this character and I have yet to find any.

Does anyone know who the character and/or actress is?

Comment: You are getting _person_ confused with _thing_, though.  Unless that is a typing error for _thin_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just discovered the answer in the answer to another question ([Who and what is the Rebellion left with at the end of The Last Jedi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177105/who-and-what-is-the-rebellion-left-with-at-the-end-of-the-last-jedi)). The character is [Commander Larma D'Acy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Larma_D%27Acy) played by Amanda Lawrence.

[image]

Somehow when I found Amanda Lawrence's name in IMDB and did an image search, the images I found didn't look right.